# What tense is the sentence "He would go to finish the job?"

Tags: will-would

What tense is the sentence "He would go to finish the job?"

Other examples, "He would leave the store." "He would decide to help him."

Answer (score 1):

Being a modal word, **would** doesn't really have a tense. Modal auxiliaries don't inflect. However, you can think of it as having a past tense, since **would** is also a past form of **will**. Having no tense doesn't preclude it from expressing it though. In your examples it could mean:

1. A habitual action - there were times in the past when he would (used to) leave the store, help him etc. **Would** here means "regularly".
2. A hypothetical - he would decide to help him (,if given enough reasons to).
3. Future in the past or reported speech - (I knew) he would decide to help him / (he said) he would go and finish the job.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context, but "would" can be the past tense of will.

Example ([British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar/will-or-would)):

> I thought I would be late …… so I would have to take the train.